# Android : Add items to a ListView dynamically without disordering

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, listactivity

In a `ListActivity`, I have a "More" `Button` below the list.

When I click on it, the result add to the list properly, but **the problem is** that the button disappear after this! I want it stay there and the user be able to load more data again of course!

The code is :

```
btnMoreItems.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // some fake data
            for (int i = 10; i < 20; i++) {
                data.add( // fake data to attach to the list //);
            }

            setListAdapter(new MyCustomArrayAdapter(MyListActivity.this, data));
        }
    });
```

and the layout is some like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/android:empty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/myListEmpty" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnMoreItemsLoad"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    → → android:layout_below="@+id/android:list ← ← ← ← ←
        android:text="@string/moreItems" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

When the activity load for first time, the button is in the right place. But when clicked it disappear behind the added items.

With this line : **`android:layout_below="@+id/android:list`** I expect that the button stay in its position( i mean below the last item in the list)

Thank for any help...

Answer (score 0):

Change layout to the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:align_parentTop="true"   ← ← ← ← ←
        android:layout_weight="1"  ← ← ← ← ←
        android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp" >
    </ListView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/android:empty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/myListEmpty" />

    <Button
        android:layout_weight="0" ← ← ← ← ←
        android:align_parentBottom="true"  ← ← ← ← ←
        android:id="@+id/btnMoreItemsLoad"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/android:list
        android:text="@string/moreItems" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: thanks but there is warning about this : "layout_weight"   Invalid layout param in a RelativeLayout: layout_weight

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/android:empty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/myListEmpty" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/android:empty"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" >
    </ListView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnMoreItemsLoad"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_below="@+id/android:list"
        android:text="@string/moreItems" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks... but there is not significant change to my code! You add only "layout_marginTop="5dp"" to ListView. Are you were sure this chould solve!?  I try this, it's not solve the problem...

Comment: Not only top margin, I hv added layout:below in listview also..as per my  understanding it shl work

Comment: I try this, but not work! In fact only one of them ( ListView & TextBox ) shown! If there is no items in list, ListView is hidden and otherwise if list is not empty, TextBox is will hide!

Comment: So it's not necessary to add layout_below to ListView!

Comment: Give height to listview like layout-height=50dp